# Add a line to a file using fwrite

Tags: php, file-io

Ive been trying to work this out:

```
if(isset($_POST['server'])):
    $block = $_POST['ip'];
    $file_handle = fopen($file, "a+");
    $content = "\n" . $block;
    fwrite($file_handle, $content);
    fclose($file_handle);
endif;
```

just doesnt write it in the file. I do have the $file stated.

Comment: do you have proper permissions to write to the file?

Comment: Yep, I gave 755 permission to both files [ txt + this php file ]

Comment: You didn't test whether the file was opened successfully.  How do you know there's not something stopping it?  For example, the apache user (or whatever is running your script) might not have write permissions on the directory.

Comment: @beater 755 is only writable by the file's owner.  What is the file's user and group?

Comment: `755` means only the owner can write. Who is the owner?

Comment: All of the files have the same owner, the interesting thig is once I removed the if(isset.. ) part it worked, any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a check in to see if the fopen is successful

```
if($filehandle) {
    // do something
}
```

I suspect you will find that the file is not open

Comment: The file is open, Interesting, Once I took the isset part out it worked, any idea why?

Comment: @Beater is server set in the post ? If not that code block would not be executed